# Angular 4 option selected by default in template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-select, selected

I want to have an option selected by default but it only works if I remove the NgModel directive from the select.

```
<select id="privileges" name="privileges" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value" required>
   <option [selected]="(user | async).privileges == Administrador" value="Administrador">Administrador</option>
   <option value="Empleado">Empleado</option>
</select>
```

If I remove the ngmodel directive if it works perfectly but obviously it's not what I need.

Comment: This code looks perfectly fine, make sure your "value" in controller is equal either "Administrator" or "Empleado", if it is not it is obvious that select will be empty, also make sure that you import FormsModule or NgModelModule.

Comment: The data in the controller is fine. And in fact, removing the directive in Model everything works fine. Why does not adding this directive stop working? What could be happening there?

Answer (score 1):

`[selected]="..."` doesn't work with `ngModel`.

To select a value, assign the value to your `value` field.
Angular will make the option the selected, where `value="..."` is equal to the value assigned to the `value` field used in `[(ngModel)]="value"`.

If the used value is not a string, use `[ngValue]="..."` instead of `[value]="..."` or `value="{{...}}"`.

Comment: And how do I get the data to the controller? If I do not place the ngModel the value of the select does not appear in the object.

Comment: `user.subscribe(val => this.value = privileges == Administrador)` or similar. Hard to tell without seeing more of your code. What is `Administrator` anyway? If this is a string, you need add quotes (`... == 'Administrator'`) (but not on `selected="..."` because that doesn't work with `ngModel` as mentioned)